# MySQL replicate a slave to another DB with only insert/update commands

Tags: mysql

I have a sensible project running with Master > Slave replication and it's working fine for more than 6 months. The master database is hosted in a hosting provider and the slave on one of my local machines.

The replication is fully integrated with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` commands, as it should be.

I'd like now to replicate the commands performed on the slave to another two separated databases. The two databases would have two different approaches:

1. The first one will only accept `INSERT` and `UPDATE` commands
2. The second one will only accept `INSERT` commands

[image]

I have read similar topics like:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18037/replication-with-only-update-and-insert,
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103020/replication-in-same-server-within-different-databases-mysql-5-6
- [Mysql trigger events in a row based master-slave replication on slave-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679785/mysql-trigger-events-in-a-row-based-master-slave-replication-on-slave-side)

And it seems the best approach would be using triggers, but I have not found an example where I could trigger the replication of all tables (the database has about 70 tables and it is expected to grow more).

- Is the trigger approach the right way to do it?
- What other options can I use to accomplish my goal?

On my local machine I'm running Xampp, where I have the clone/slave database. I'd like to have two more databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

Here's how I did it:

1. Listen to `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries being executed in the project
2. Save those queries into DB Master
3. It is instantly replicated in the DB Slave
4. Create a PHP script that runs every minute and loops through DB rows (local machine)
5. Write `INSERT` and `UPDATE` commands into DB Slave 2 (local machine)
6. Write `INSERT` commands into DB Slave 3 (local machine)
7. Delete the rows in the DB Master
8. Repeat